# Recommended SQL Server / T-SQL book

Tags: .net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, database-performance

I'm looking for some book about SQL Server 2008 and T-SQL, let's say intermediate (focus on stored procedures, indexing, optimizations, performance), not taking too much on simple create/insert/select ;)

It will be also great with some .NET featues, also on improving performance mainly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my favorite book for touching on a little of everything (and providing references to where you can find more detailed info):

> MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-432): Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 - Implementation and Maintenance
>   ISBN 13:    9780735626058

I like the test-prep books in general -- not that I take the tests usually (unless I'm updating my resume), but just because they have pretty good coverage, and a lot of good references.

Otherwise, the 'Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming'

> Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008 T-SQL Programming (Developer Reference)
>   ISBN-13: 978-0735626027 ISBN-10: 0735626022

or TSQL-Querying

> Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008 T-SQL Querying (Developer Reference)
>   ISBN-13: 978-0735626034 ISBN-10: 0735626030

Comment: @JakubJedryszek - thanks - removed links

Answer (score 2):

try "SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled" to cover your sql needs
[image: SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled]

Answer (score 0):

I vote for Murach's *SQL Server 2008 For Developers*. I am currently enjoying going through the book. Its a very easy layout, esppecially if you are always putting it down/picking it up.